# create object in for loop

Tags: c++, object

I have the following for loop, in this foor loop I create an object kw.

```
The class keywords (string, vector<pair<int,string>>, vector<string>)

for(size_t i = 0; i < names.size();i++)
{
      Keywords kw (names[i].c_str(),vreg, stopWords);
      Document d = kw.extractKeywords();
      v_doc.push_back(d);
}
```

I think that there is a problem in this for loop. I thought that it might be better if i take the Keywords out of the for loop, since i just need to create that object once.

```
Keywords kw (vreg, stopWords);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < names.size();i++)
    {

          Document d = kw.extractKeywords(names[i].c_str());
          v_doc.push_back(d);
    }
```

When I do that I don't get the right output. Can you please give me a hint thank you.

Hani.

This class is being used to extract keywords out of an xml File. I provided the:

- Class constructor
- Copy Constructor
- Setters and getters
- Destructors

Do you think that there is a problem in the copy constructor

```
Keywords::Keywords(string xmlF,vector<pair<int, string>> re,vector<string> sw)
{
    // Setter for string: the path of the xml File
    setXml(xmlF);
    // Setter for the vector<pair<int, string>> re
    setRegularExpression(re);
    //setter for vector<string> sw
    setStopWords(sw);
}

//FREE MEMORY
Keywords::~Keywords()
{

    sw.clear();
    vreg.clear();
}

void Keywords::setRegularExpression(vector<pair<int, string>>   re)
{
    vreg = re;
}

vector<pair<int, string>>   Keywords::getRegularExpression()
{
    return vreg;
}

void Keywords::setStopWords(vector<string> s)
{
    sw = s;
}

vector<string> Keywords::getStopWords()
{
    return sw;
}

void Keywords::setXml(string xmlF)
{
    xmlFile = xmlF;

}

///COPY CONSTRUCTOR
Keywords::Keywords(const Keywords& other):vreg(other.vreg),sw(other.sw)
{

}
```

Comment: Do you *really* want us to guess what the `Keywords` class is? Seriously, how can we know?

Comment: oh wait i'll put the code sorry. I just wanted to know if it's a good practice to do that.

Comment: Oh sure there is a good practice for "*that*". The only (and most important) question is, what is "*that*", exactly? ;)

Comment: Your question isn't informative enough. What is the definition of the class `Keywords`? How is `extractKeywords` defined? What is the output you're hoping for? We need these tidbits of information in order to help you ;-) EDIT: Okay, nevermind :)

Comment: I adde the class. The problem is that i am getting during run time Bad::Alloc()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`kw` is allocated in the second code only once, but in the first code for each loop iteration

In non runtime critical code it is good practice to construct objects in a RAII fashion.

Comment: Yes I just need to use it once. is there a problem in the first part of the code? I mean is it a good practice?